# Android CountDownTimer

Tags: android, countdowntimer

When writing :

```
 CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(1000, 100) 
 {
      @Override
       public void onTick(long l) 
       {

       }

       @Override
       public void onFinish() 
       {

       };
 }.start();
```

are we actually starting a new thread that handles ticks?  If not, what is really happening?

Answer (score 11):

`CountDownTimer`'s [implementation](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/os/CountDownTimer.java&q=package:android%20CountDownTimer&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) uses `Handler` and `sendMessageDelayed()`, so no background thread is needed. This does mean that the timer will not update if you are tying up the main application thread elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Definition from multiple publications, tried and tested:

"Another timer is provided with the **built-in class CountDownTimer**.This encapsulates the creation of a background thread and the handler queuing into a convenient class call..."

Comment: There is no background thread created, look at the [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/os/CountDownTimer.java).