# display a countdown timer in the alert dialog box

Tags: android, timer, android-alertdialog

How do i display a countdown timer in my alert box .i want to notify the user that the session will end in 5 minutes and show a timer running in the alert pop up box ..

Comment: what about to use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried and any logcat errors.

Comment: Also check this: [Android CountDownTimer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691026/android-countdowntimer)

Comment: timer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000)
 
  {
   
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
   {}

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you should have an `alertDialog` for the pop-up box:

```
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();  
alertDialog.setTitle("Alert 3");  
alertDialog.setMessage("00:10");
alertDialog.show();   // 

new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
       alertDialog.setMessage("00:"+ (millisUntilFinished/1000));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: thanq soo much... will try it out immediately

Comment: you should also read the `countDownTimer` and the `AlertDialog` documentation

Comment: what if i want to show the alert box after a fixed time ..say 10 minutes after the user has started the activity ... and once the alert box appears tell the user that in 5 minutes the session will expire ..???

Comment: first alert box will be in the onFinish of a timer and den from der call another timer ?? then will i be able to display the time in the alert box

Comment: @thepoosh: how could i add cancel button on alertDialog.so i can stop countdown???

Answer (score 0):

Put a TextView in the dialog layout.  Then using a Handler.postDelayed() method (or a CountDownTimer, or a Timer, or [...]), refresh the value displayed on the TextView.