# Android Asynctask update UI and computation

Tags: android

I am a beginner at android/java development and I have just started learning about asynctask. I am trying to create an application that counts up (updating the ui thread with each incremental count) with a variable delay, and I am not sure how to pass the values into the asynctask, or even get it to work.

```
/*I have an editText (I used editText on purpose) named log, which is supposed 
to be the output of the operation. 
count is the number of counting up that I want the log to display. 
time is the sleep delay I wish to set inbetween printing each number.*/

    public class backgroundsend extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
//and I want i to be the current count of the number to be displayed.
       for (int i=1; i<count+1; i++){
            try {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        log.setText(log.getText() +i);
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(time);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        log.setText(log.getText() + "Operation Ended \n\n");
    }
}
```

Now this code does not compile properly because it wants i to be a final variable, and I don't know how to make the i in for loop into a final variable, if possible. I tried using a dummy variable and adding +1 every loop run and it still doesn't work. Additionally, when I tried to use the for loop/asynctask without the i value (a constant value) it would run but the ui thread would still hang like normal on large values. Can somebody give me insight as to what I am doing wrong, and how I should correct it? Thank you.

Comment: Aside from the comments in the answer from codeMagic, an `AsyncTask` really isn't the way to do what you want. A better way is to use a `Handler` - see this blog post... http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html

Comment: @Squonk good article! But I'm curious why `Handler` is better than `AsyncTask` here. Is it faster or more efficient in some way? If it mentioned it in the article, I apologize, maybe I missed something.

Comment: It is more efficient and simpler to use a `Handler`. The `AsyncTask` class is actually really quite complex and to simply update a `TextView` periodically is way more than you need. The use of `postDelayed(...)` with a `Handler` is more versatile and `Handlers` can be used in many more ways with simpler code.

Comment: @Squonk thanks for your response. I agree that `AsyncTask` is overkill here but I just wasn't sure if performance-wise it was more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Couple problems.

1. Don't use `runOnUiThread()` anywhere in `AsyncTask`...it defeats the purpose. All functions of `AsyncTask` run on the `UI Thread` **except for** `doInBackground()` so the idea is to do heavy work in `doInBackground()` and update `UI` in the other functions.
2. You have `onPostExecute()` expecting a `String` but you are returning `null` from `doInBackground()` and that function passes its `result` (if there should be one) to `onPostExecute()`
3. You can pass updates to `onProgressUpdate()` by calling `publishProgress()` in `doInBackground()`

To fix this you could do something like

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
       for (int i=1; i<count+1; i++)
       {
            publishProgress(i);   update UI in onProgressUpdate()
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } 
     }
        return "Operation Ended \n\n";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
       log.setText(log.getText() + result);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) 
    {
        // update UI here 
    }
```

I don't know how you are calling the task so I don't know what you are doing wrong there but you can do something like

```
backgroundsend myTask = new backgroundsend();  // can pass params to a constructor if needed
myTask.execute(...); // the ... is where you would put params to pass to doInBackground()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. codeMagic. For further reference if anybody else wishes to learn something like this, I used what Squonik wrote/what codeMagic wrote and I also used [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html) as it is more suited to my application.

It works now, although I need time to absorb the knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Thread.sleep() is a bad way to delay repetitions:

[Why using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep() is a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995938/why-using-system-threading-thread-sleep-is-a-bad-practice)

You can use a CountDownTimer:

[Android CountDownTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691026/android-countdowntimer)

but if I were you, I would post a delayed execution N-times since you already have an existing view (your text field):

```
// number of repetitions
private static final int REPETITIONS = 5;
// delay in mills
private static final int DELAY = 100;
// count
private int count;
final Runnable countingRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (count < REPETITIONS)  {
            count = count + 1;
            log.postDelayed(countingRunnable, DELAY);
        }
        else {
            // TODO call a method, notify a listener or whatnot your updates are over
        }
    }
};
...
// then in your place where you want to trigger the counting
log.postDelayed(countingRunnable, DELAY);
...
// and in `Activity|Fragment.onDestroy()` ensure to remove the callbacks
log.removeCallbacks(countingRunnable);
```